# _meta.get_field() 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

When trying to access the `_meta` api in a class based view, I get:

> 'method' object is not subscriptable

For example, this occurs when trying to get a `verbose_name` for a field using `_meta.get_field` in a `ListView` CBV:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    print(self.model._meta.get_field['email'].verbose_name)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get_field in _meta is function, not array

```
get_field(field)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    print(self.model._meta.get_field('email').verbose_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

A demo from Django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_field):

```py
>>> User._meta.get_field('username')
<django.db.models.fields.CharField: username>
```

Seems like you used the wrong brackets